# If $f$ is analytic in $D$ and $|f(z)|<M$ everywhere on $|z|=1$, show for all $z:|z|<1$, $|f(z)| \leq M |\frac{z-a}{\bar a z - 1}|$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Suppose $f(a)=0$ for some $|a|<1$. If $f$ is analytic in $D$ containing the unit disk and $|f(z)|<M$ finite for all $z:|z|=1$, show for all $z:|z|<1$, that
>   $$
> |f(z)| \leq M \left|\frac{z-a}{\bar a z - 1}\right|.
> $$

**Attempt**

Since $f(a)=0$,
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C \frac{f(z) dz}{z} = 0.
$$
So
$$
\left| \int_C \frac{f(z) dz}{z} \right|
\leq \int_C \frac{|f(z)|}{|z|}dz
\leq M \int_C \frac{1}{|z|}dz
= M 2 \pi.
$$
But is there a relationship between $\int_C \frac{1}{|z|}dz$ and $\left|\frac{z-a}{\bar a z - 1}\right|$? It seems like the integral is just equal to $2\pi$. I need a better bound.

Perhaps we should use the fact that $w = \frac{z-a}{\overline a z - 1}$ maps the closed unit disk in the $z$-plane to the closed unit disk in the $w$-plane, but I don't know if this works with my approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second idea is the one that works. $T(z) = \frac{z-a}{\overline a z - 1}$ maps the unit disk onto itself, with $T(a) = 0$ and $|T(z)| = 1$
for $|z| = 1$.

Now apply the maximum modulus principle to $\frac fT$ and conclude that
$|f(z)| \le M |T(z)|$ in the unit disk.

Answer (score 0):

Take the Blashke Factor $$ \phi_a (z)= \frac{a-z}{1- \bar{a}z} $$ ,
which interchanges 0 and a. To apply Scawrcz(probably the spelling is incorrect)
define a function $$ g= \frac{1}{M} fo \phi_a $$ . Then all the hypothesis of the S-lemma is easily verified . so we get $$ |g(z)| \leq |z| $$ . invert z in  $ \phi_a $ to get your desired conclusion.